# How can I collect statisctic for each backend separate in Varnish?

Tags: cdn, backend, varnish, stat

I need to know how many traffic each customer use in our CDN. As I undersand, varnishstat command return statistic for all backend but i need to know traffic for each backend.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.

But with Varnish 3, you can customize log format and then parse/split your log file.